# primitive roots $g^a \mod{p}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

$p$ prime, $g$ primitive root $\mod{p}$, $0 \leq a \leq p-2$

Show:

$g^a \mod{p}$ is a primitive root $\mod{p}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ gcd($a,p-1) = 1$

Ideas:

$g^a \mod{p}$ is a primitive root if $ord(g^a)=p-1$, so thats the left side. But how can i show the equivalence?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091626/show-that-if-o-ma-h-for-all-k-ge-1-o-mak-frach-h-k?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you can show that for any cyclic group $G$ of order $n$ and any generator $g$ of $G$, the order of $g^a$ is equal to $\dfrac n{n\wedge a}$.