# Is there a method to find all primitive roots for some integer $n$?

Tags: number-theory

I'm finding all the primitive roots of $3^3 =27$. 
I know that if $r$ is a primitive root of $p$, then it is also primitive root of $p^k$. 
But how do we find all candidates of primitive roots of the form $p^k$ ?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104189/primitive-roots-ga-modp

Comment: The reason I suggest the above as a duplicate is that the answer is "it's hard even for primes."  Of course the question texts are not the same, but nevertheless the answer is there.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such a method!
But for some special primes $p$ We can find
1)the numbers $3,5,7$ are primitive roots modulo every prime number of the form $2^n+1$ for natural $n\gt1$.
Moreover, for these primes every non residue number modulo the prime number is primitive root!
2)$p,q$ are odd prime numbers such that, $p=4q+1$, then the number $2$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.
3)$p,q$ are odd prime numbers such that, $p=2q+1$, then every non residue modulo $p$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ except one of them. 
And many others...